# left join compare with and md5(concat()) mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join

First of all, I'm sorry for my english.

I want to compare two records with md5 generated:

I insert information in table2 that I bring from the table1

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id_table_2, hash_string) 
SELECT t.id, MD5 (CONCAT (t.firstname, t.lastname)) AS hash_string
FROM table1 t WHERE t.id = $some_value
```

After that I want to know what records from table1 there's no exists in table2, but I can´t obtain the result I want. I do this:

```
SELECT t.id, MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) , ti.hash_string 
FROM table1 t 
    LEFT JOIN table2 ti ON (t.id = ti.id_table_2 
    AND MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) != ti.hash_string)
    WHERE t.state = 2
```

but It doesn´t work.

What I want are the records from Table 1 that are not in table2, but from there, if there md5 hash is different also show it. But I failed to get it. I appreciate all the help you can give me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this, see the last added line and I also changed `!=` to `=`:

```
SELECT t.id, MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) , ti.hash_string 
FROM      table1 t 
LEFT JOIN table2 ti ON (t.id = ti.id_table_2 
                   AND MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) = ti.hash_string)
WHERE t.state = 2
  AND ti.id_table_2 IS NULL
```

The basic form of this trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM      a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: excellent biziclop, that's works for me. Thanks a lot man. That's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should help you (move the hash_string out of join and append as where clause):

```
SELECT t.id, MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) , ti.hash_string 
FROM table1 t 
LEFT JOIN table2 ti ON (t.id = ti.id_table_2)
WHERE t.state = 2 
   AND MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) != ti.hash_string 
   AND ti.id_table_2 is NULL;
```

Comment: yogendra thanks, I tried this too but did not work. He showed me all the records. thanks

Comment: By `MD5(CONCAT(t.firstname, t.lastname)) != ti.hash_string` you should get oly record where HashString doesn't match. Added one `Null condition` also in the answer. Please check.

Comment: @AnbalMauricioPachecoGonzlez: I see you have already accepted the answer. At least vote this one to show it works for you. Also please notice the difference in `hash_string` comparison. Not sure, how important is that in your real scenarios.

Comment: @YongendraSingh, I can't even vote apparently. It tells me I have 15 reputation. Sorry for that.

Comment: @AnbalMauricioPachecoGonzlez  Not a problem! I am not advising to do so but I believe you can switch your preferences whenever you feel the need of it.